# Best practice: use languageCode or LanguageTag with multi language app

Tags: react-native, internationalization, multilingual, i18next

So I have followed a tutorial for creating a multi language React-Native app. My app now finds out the language of the device and then matches this with the translations of the app. However the tutorial (and so my coding for now as wel) uses the languageTag for matching the translations.

A German phone would be de-DE, a English phone en-US etc. As I understand at first it is the language of the device, the second is the region.

So my translations are setup as followed;

```
I18n.translations = {
  default: en,
  'en-US': en,
  'nl-NL': nl,
  'fr-FR': fr,
  'de-DE': de
};
```

However a German phone in the US would be languageTag de-US, this would not match my de-DE: de part so even thought the phone is set to use the German language, because it is in the US it will not translate to German language.

What do you all prefer? I am now thinking of using the LanguageCode to check the language. If the languageCode is 'de' use the German translation.

Would there be a reason against using the LanguageCode in stead of the LanguageTag?

Answer (score 0):

First you must have parameters in the data of the REST Server.

Example:
for english : https://example.com/en/home

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("https://example.com/en/home");
       BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
       byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       int bytesRead = 0;
       while((bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
           String text = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
           sb.append(text);
       }
       bis.close();

     return sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //on error some code
    }
```

Example:
for french: https://example.com/fr/home

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("https://example.com/fr/home");
       BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
       byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       int bytesRead = 0;
       while((bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
           String text = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
           sb.append(text);
       }
       bis.close();

     return sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //on error some code
    }
```

for translating your REST datas, you may use my tool [EasyTranslation](https://github.com/Abl1ck/EasyTranslation)
below how to use it

```
use EasyTranslation\EasyTranslation\EasyTranslation;
include('src/EasyTranslation.php');
class Example extends EasyTranslation{

public function __construct() {
    $this->setLanguage();   // Set a language or by default will check for client language (e.g. French is "fr")
    echo $this->translate('Welcome');
}
}

new Example();
```

Comment: I already have a translation working. However I wanted to know what would be best using the languageCode or languageTag.